# wordpress / divi Theme - slider content display size not working well

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I encounter some problems with the slider module on divi.

for some of the articles the width content is based on the website width and not on the module width.

here two screenshot of the problem
[image: wrong witdth]

[image]

if needed the link to the website is: hhtp://jordan-delamotte.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this following code by pasting in your theme option panel.

```
.et_pb_slider_fullwidth_off .et_pb_container {
   width: auto !important;
   display:block;
}
.et_pb_slides .et_pb_slider_container_inner{
display:block;   
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: reasons are explained by @Arghya Chowdhury

Answer (score 1):

Yes the answer is cosummately right, Actually in legacy version of divi container would use  the slider container element as **block element** now it's assigned or changed to  **table-cell** and that's why the design is getting brake.